# C# Linq multiple GroupBy and Select

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have two objects that are linked, `States` and `Cities`, so each `State` has his `Cities` and each `Citie` is linked to an `State`. I also have some `Units` that have `stateID` and `citieID` but they are not linked since i have them only in Json.

What i need is to get only the `States` and `Cities` that have `Units`. I managed to get the first two but was wondering if there was any faster way to do it since i will have to make an update on those datas everyday:

```
//unitsData have a List of Units objects, this only have stateID, citieID and the unit data
var unitsData = objUnidade.BuscaUnidades();

//unitsState have all units grouped by State, here i also only have stateID and citieID, same data as above
var unitsState = unitsData.GroupBy(x => x.codigoEstado);

//Here is where i make my search inside the unidadesEstados and select only the Estados that i need
var activeStates = unitsState.Select(est => db.States.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == est.Key)).Where(state => state != null).ToList();
```

To do the Cities search i'm doing the same but using an extra foreach, is there a way to make this better ?

Comment: Just a note: It would be easier for others if you named the variables in english.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the database multiple times.  It's better to use a SELECT ... IN query, which in LINQ looks like:

```
var units = objUnidad.BuscaUnidades();
var stateIds = units.Select(u => u.codigoEstado).ToList();
var activeStates = db.States.Where(s => stateIds.Contains(s.Id)).ToList();
```

EDIT: you asked about cities as well.  It's more of the same:

```
var cityIds = units.Select(u => u.codigoCuidad).ToList()
var activeCities = db.Cities.Where(c => cityIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
```

This solution gives you every city whose ID is referred to by a unit.  @StriplingWarrior 's solution will give you every city in (the states that have a unit).

Comment: Great, and how could i do that getting also the cities of each selected state ?

Comment: @Terkhos: `var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => stateIds.Contains(c.StateId)).ToList()`

Comment: Edited to add city solution.  Now I'm not sure whether you're looking for every city in a state that is selected, or just cities whose ID is specified by a unit; if the former, use @StriplingWarrior's query; if the latter, use mine.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel: Instead of `Contains(s)`, you need `Contains(s.Id)` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Jerry and Stripling, it worked as i wanted, about your question Jerry i wanted all the cities of a selected state.

Answer (score 1):

If `db.States` queries the database, then for each group in `unitsState` the query will get executed. If the number of states isn't extremely large, you can store them in a list.

```
var dbStates = db.States.ToList();
var activeStates = unitsState.Select(est => dbStates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == est.Key)).Where(state => state != null).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, db.States queries the database, it isn't, i have only 27 states. How could i do that getting also the cities of each selected state ?

Comment: I guess you can just select all cities from the database, store them in a list as well and group them by state afterwards.